# Jenkins Windows slave failing the Play! framework build

Tags: windows, playframework, jenkins

We are using the Play! framework and I've setup our Jenkins CI to run auto-test and other things on a master Unix machine. As a second step I want to setup a windows slave to run some in browser webdriver tests. Unfortunately my build doesn't get to that point. The source checks out fine in the workspace directory. As a first build step I run

```
play clean
```

Which seems to fail everytime. I've given full permissions to admin for that directory and I'm running the jenkins slave under that administrator like so

```
runas /noprofile /user:DOMAIN\Administrator "javaws http://jenkins:8080/computer/Keith/slave-agent.jnlp"
```

The console output I see from jenkins is:

```
Building remotely on Keith in workspace C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\My Documents\Jenkins\workspace\windows
Updating http://svnrepo..
At revision 448
no change for http://svnrepo.. since the previous build
play path is C:\Software\Play\play
Executing C:\Software\Play\play clean "C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\My Documents\Jenkins\workspace\windows" 
[windows] $ C:\Software\Play\play clean "C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\My Documents\Jenkins\workspace\windows"
Build step 'Play!' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Note that when I run the command below manually on the windows box it works fine:

```
C:\Software\Play\play clean "C:\Documents and Settings\administrator\My Documents\Jenkins\workspace\windows"
```

Anyone got any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and I solved it by adding `.bat` at the end of play path. In your case, you should configure play path in jenkins as `C:\Software\Play\play.bat` (not just `C:\Software\Play\play`).