# Can't build play framework project in Jenkins

Tags: build, jenkins, playframework-2.0, build-automation

I'm wondering if anyone else has run into this issue with Jenkins 1.535 and the play framework.

In my company, one of the projects uses the play framework.  We're using play version 2.1.1.  From the cmd line, I can run play clean or play compile and it runs without problems.

```
cd /git/big-data/dw
play clean
[info] Loading project definition from /git/big-data/dw/project
[info] Set current project to dw (in build file:/git/big-data/dw/)
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Oct 23, 2013 10:17:27 AM
```

I installed the play plugin onto Jenkins and configured the path on where to find play.

Within the job, I entered the application path (relative to workspace), and added a build step to use play.  In this step, I just put 'clean' as the command.

[image]

However, when I build this project in Jenkins, it says there's an invalid command and errors out.  We can see in the log below that clean succeeded.  I don't know where this invalid command is b/c the only command I put is `clean`.  Thanks in advance for any light you can shed on this issue.

Log from Jenkins

```
Executing /opt/play-2.1.1/play clean "/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Debug_play/workspace/dw" 
[dw] $ /opt/play-2.1.1/play clean /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Debug_play/workspace/dw
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mLoading project definition from /home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Debug_play/workspace/dw/project[0m
[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mSet current project to dw (in build file:/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Debug_play/workspace/dw/)[0m
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 0 s, completed Oct 23, 2013 10:20:41 AM[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mNot a valid command: /[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m/home/jenkins/.jenkins/jobs/Debug_play/workspace/dw[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m ^[0m
****************************************************
* ERROR!!! while executing clean
****************************************************
Build step 'Play!' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the same problem as here: [Jenkins Windows slave failing the Play! framework build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8937835/jenkins-windows-slave-failing-the-play-framework-build?rq=1)

So... you should add .sh or .run in the end of "/opt/play-2.1.1/play" :) Maybe magic will happen.

Comment: I have a similiar problem but unfortunately adding ".sh" in the Jenkins configuration did not do the trick (using Play 2.21).

`[0m[[0minfo[0m] [0mSet current project to myProject (in build file:/opt/myProject/)[0m
[0m[[32msuccess[0m] [0mTotal time: 0 s, completed Apr 10, 2015 12:01:55 PM[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mExpected symbol[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0mNot a valid command: /[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m/opt/myProject[0m
[0m[[31merror[0m] [0m ^[0m`

It seems like the plugin calls the value of the job's "Play! application path" at the end.